# How to show scrollbar for tablayout?

Tags: android, xml, android-tablayout

I need to show a scrollbar on a horizontally scrolling tab layout.

I have tried the following without success:

```
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"

                    app:tabMode="scrollable"
                    android:scrollIndicators="bottom"
                    android:scrollbarTrackHorizontal="@color/black"
                    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                    android:scrollbarSize="2dp"
                    android:isScrollContainer="true"
                    android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
                    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
                    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
                    android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@android:color/darker_gray"

    //Not relevant parts below
   app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/blue"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTextAppearance"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/very_light_gray"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/blue"/>
```

Comment: cover your TabLayout with horizontalscrollview. And set styles

Comment: you mean, place tablayout inside a horizontalscrollview parent?

Comment: yes that is what i mean

Comment: I can get the horizontal scrollbar to show if I add a horizontal scollview parent, but the problem is that the tablayout method: setScrollPosition() does not make the tablayout visibly scroll to the correct position (although the selected tab does update).

Answer (score 2):

just this code : 
app:tabMode="scrollable"

Answer (score 1):

Try to set indicator height.

```
app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"
```

Comment: no, that sets the active tab indicator height. I mean the scroll position % indicator.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

`tabLayout.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);`